# apex как задать из js или pl/sql другого элемента process settings attribute?

Tags: javascript, oracle, excel, plsql, oracle-apex

Я уже загружаю первую страницу xls. У меня есть file_browser, button и процесс.
1) надо динамически (с помощью list) задать несколько страниц sheets для плагина excel2collection по выбору пользователя.
2) как определить количество страниц в загружаемом  xls?
Я искала ответ и на русском и на английском и в документации, пока не нашла.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если минусуете вопрос, то объясните, почему.

Comment: Смею предположить, что минусуют из-за отсутствия кода. Кода примера и кода, как вы пытались решить проблему.